# Is PostgreSQL peer authentication safe for production?

Tags: postgresql, security, authentication

PostgreSQL peer authentication is a source of many questions on this website, but once you understand how it works, it looks pretty awesome.

For example, I can have my application connecting to the development database without supplying username and password.

So, my question is, can I use peer authentication on a production server? Is it safe enough?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peer` is very useful for many kinds of deployments - e.g. when you want to allow people to log in with local unix user accounts and get quick DB access as a matching PostgreSQL user.

It's not great for webapps, because you generally want each webapp to have its own user. So you usually use `md5` for them.

I often combine the two. For webapps allow `md5` to their private DB only - over `local` sockets if the driver supports it, otherwise over `host` connections from `localhost`. Allow `peer` for local users to any DB, including the webapp DBs. If you want to have only one user in each db (so you can ignore permissions - which I don't recommend, but I know some people do) you can use a `pg_ident.conf` mapping to allow people to authenticate via `peer` as users other than their default user name.

Then you may add `hostssl` connections from the outside world via `md5` or `gssapi` (kerberos), or `sspi` if it's a Windows DB host.

Authentication methods aren't an all or nothing thing. There's a reason it's easy to provide a list of alternatives and pick the first matching one.

Comment: The reason why I liked peer authentication in the first place is that I can avoid having a password written in plain text in a config file or environmental variable. So I can just create an OS user for my webapp, pick a nice long password for it and not worry about my config files leaking anywhere.

Comment: @art-solopov It's possible to use `peer` that way; the problem is that anyone who breaks into your web server has an easier time getting access to all the DBs for all your apps. They can do so with `md5` anyway, since the webserver has to have the ability to read the config files with the credentials for each app, but it'll take them a little longer at least. The only really secure way to do it is run each app under its own user as a daemon (with fastcgi/scgi/whatever) and have the web server just proxy for the apps.

Comment: But it'd have them crack through SSH to get to the database, wouldn't they?

P. S. I'm planning on using Ruby, so I'd have to install Nginx and reverse-proxy to actual application servers.

Comment: @art-solopov Well, in that case `peer` for each app, with each app running in its own account, makes a lot of sense.